# How to get default SystemSoundID within iOS app?

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, ios9

This is how I play sound:

```
var soundID: SystemSoundID = 1016
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
```

But this is not default system sound set by user. Is there a way to get the one assigned by user to respect its choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is NO API to get the user selected system sound.

In case if you want to access any specific sound files you can go through this [list](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) for the Sound Id's.